# Suggestion for a light weight distro of linux

Tags: unity

I'am a new ubuntu user. I install ubuntu 14.04 LTS unity distro. At first it was fast enough to work with. But as soon as I install more apps it becomes impossible to work with as it becomes so slow in case of multi-tasking. 
So can any one suggest a stable version of debian package that I can install ?
Oh another thing, I have installed a lot of software. How can I backup them and transfer then to new OS?

Hardware specification:
Intel core i3 2.66GHz,
4GB RAM,
6 GB swap memory,
Dell Inspiron 15 Intel Core i3-390M 2.66GHz 15.6in Laptop

Comment: [Lubuntu](http://lubuntu.net/) and [Xubuntu](http://xubuntu.org/getxubuntu/) are lighter weight official Ubuntu flavours and there is the [Classic Desktop](http://askubuntu.com/q/58172/107450).  If you want to look at a non Ubuntu Linux your question is off topic here but you can ask in [Ubuntu, Linux and OS chat](http://ubuntuforums.org/forumdisplay.php?f=434) on the [Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/).

Comment: See [How to know which Ubuntu is right for my hardware?](http://askubuntu.com/q/206407/22949), but since you seem to be interested in non-Ubuntu distros too, Warren Hill is correct: you should ask somewhere questions that aren't about Ubuntu are supported.

Comment: Finally solved the problem... Actually this config. hardware runs well in with ubuntu 14.04LTS but main problem occured when I installed Oracle 11g. Oracle was not configured properly which caused me a lot of time. I suggest all of u to be careful when installing oracle 11g. A great post is here to install Oracle 11g. http://meandmyubuntulinux.blogspot.com/2012/05/installing-oracle-11g-r2-express.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a link to [Distrowatch](http://distrowatch.com/search.php?ostype=All&category=Old%20Computers&origin=All&basedon=All&notbasedon=None&desktop=All&architecture=All&status=Active), you can choose the Netbooks from the drop down menu, if the Old computer list is not enough :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stick to Ubuntu, there is Xubuntu that will be happy with this setup. Lubuntu is for even weaker machines, I run previous LTS on 64Mb of RAM.

If your are in for adventure, try Gentoo. It is not scary if you read manuals, and very rewarding in terms of result and understanding any Linux internals.